# Force XCode to output 32bit code?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have some cpp code which I transfered from Linux to OSX. The problem is that it includes a lot of encryption handling so the code is very picky about 64Bit enhancements.

Is there a way to tell xcode that it should not create 64Bit code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode 4.1, Select the project from the list of files on the left.  Select the target.
Go to the `Build Settings` tab.  Search for `Architectures` setting.  Select `32-bit Intel`.

In a previous version of Xcode, just double click on the target and find the same Architectures selection.